# Checking for and Removing elements in Java HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to check for and remove elements, using a HashMap in Java.  Its keys are a type I created called ClusterKey, and its values are a type I created called ClusterValue.

Here is the code that is causing issues:

```
ClusterKey ck = new ClusterKey(Long.parseLong(split[0].split("=")[1]), 
                        Integer.parseInt(split[1].split("ey")[1]));
if (arg == 0) keys.put(ck, new ClusterValue(index, false));
if (arg == 1) {
    if (keys.containsKey(ck)) {
        index = keys.get(ck).messageNo;
        keys.remove(ck);
    }
    keys.put(ck, new ClusterValue(index, true));
}
```

The problem is that even when the ClusterKey is the same as an existing ClusterKey, containsKey() and remove() do not seem to recognize it as equal.  I have implemented equals() in class ClusterKey to override Java's equals() method, as follows:

```
class ClusterKey {
    long firstKey;
    int secondKey;
    public ClusterKey(long firstKey, int secondKey) {
        this.firstKey = firstKey;
        this.secondKey = secondKey;
    } public boolean equals(Object otherKey) {
        return this.firstKey == ((ClusterKey) otherKey).firstKey && this.secondKey == ((ClusterKey) otherKey).secondKey;
    }
}
```

So, I'm quite confused.  Thanks so much for your help.

Regards,
Rebecca

UPDATE: Thank you for your advice and feedback on my code.  I was able to solve the problem by adding hashCode() to ClusterKey, as follows:

```
    } public boolean equals(Object otherKey) {
        return this.firstKey == ((ClusterKey) otherKey).firstKey && this.secondKey == ((ClusterKey) otherKey).secondKey;
    } public int hashCode() {
        return (int) firstKey + secondKey;
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement `hashCode`? That `hash` part is important.

Comment: Right, _always_ implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` together.

Comment: Get a copy of *Effective Java* (2nd ed. if possible) by Joshua Bloch and read Items 8 and 9 on `hashCode()` and `equals()`. There are a lot of nuances to be aware of, and Bloch covers them thoroughly.

Comment: You should be able to just call `put()`, without removing the key first (it'll overwrite, once you deal with `hashCode()`).  Beyond that, I'm a little suspicious about the use of `arg`, as it looks like you're using it as a boolean argument, which isn't good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any Hash enabled data structure (like `HashMap`, `HashSet`) to work correctly its elements must override `hashCode()` in addition to the `equals()` method. The reason being that the hash code is used to identify the bucket in which to put the element (during insertion) or search in (using `equals()` during a lookup).

If you do not override `hashCode()`, the default implementation from `Object#hashCode()` is used which would return different values even for the objects that you consider equivalent (the `equals()` method returns *true* for).

This is why your

```
 hashMap.containsKey(ClusterKey key)
```

calls are failing in spite of the key already being present. Since, the hash codes don't match the `HashMap` never looks for the key in the right bucket. Hence, your `equals()` never gets called here.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), not just `equals`, for your `ClusterKey` to work well as a key in a `HashMap`.

Specifically, quoting from the linked Javadocs:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Comment: And the `equals()` method, to be compliant with the contract, should accept nulls and any kinds of objects. Not just ClusterKey instances. It's not supposed to throw ClassCastException or NullPointerException.